# Any chart gantt chart displaying incorrect date in timeline

Tags: date, header, timeline, gantt-chart, anychart

[Gantt chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgoX9.png)

In any chart wrong date is showing as you can see from the image, 14th March is the actual date given but the output is displaced by 1 and showing 13th March.

I googled all over and found nothing

Comment: Could you please provide more information, such as HTML, CSS, JS, Data, and your AnyChart version? This will allow us to reproduce the problem on our end and provide you with a solution.

Comment: Hi I'm using the data given the quick start (Resource chart). There also the date is one day before the actual given

Comment: Thank you for responding! We will look into this issue and get back to you as soon as we have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we were unable to reproduce the problem. 
However, almost every date-related issue can be solved by [adjusting the zoom level](https://docs.anychart.com/Gantt_Chart/Basic_Settings#zooming).

```
// zoom the timeline to the given dates
function zoomToDates() {
  chart.zoomTo(Date.UTC(2018, 1, 3), Date.UTC(2018, 1, 6));
}
```

We encourage you to try out the [zoom setting demo](https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/GANTT_Basic_Settings_09) in our Playground.
We hope you find this solution to be suitable for you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will definitely go through what you suggested. I suspect there is a problem with the time zone. My timezone is Indian Standard time (IST Asia/Calcutta GMT+05:30). I added anychart.format.outputTimezone( (-18 * 60)); line to fix it temporarily.